# merge several input in one python

Tags: python

My input will be several separate line in the same form. I don't know how can I merge these inputs to one object.

For example:

```
Robin 590.00 343.05 3333.00 
Max 45.00 234.44 3443.55
```

and I would like to have these data in one expression

```
(data = '''Robin 590.00 343.05 3333.00 Max 45.00 234.44 3443.55 ''')
```

because I want to execute this code (I have to sum up last value of every input line):

```
result = sum(float(x.split()[-1]) for x in data.splitlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things that you need to read a file are in the [python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). More specifically, you can use the [with open](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) command to get a list as shown below. The list comprehension is to remove any trailing new line characters ([strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)) and keep your data in a variable, since f will be closed as soon as you exit the with clause.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    fout = [fone.strip('\n')for fone in f]

print(fout)
```